# NodeJS sync flow

Tags: node.js, synchronization

Hello i have been using a library called `deasync` it allows me to get things done in a cleaner way, i have a method like this,

```
syncGetMany: function(model, query){
        var ret;
        setTimeout(function(){

         model.find(query, (error, body) => {
            if(body){
                //Awesome got the data
                ret=  body
            }
            else{

                 //What a cruel world

                // No data, fall back to an empty array
                ret = [];
            }

        });

        },0);
        while(ret === undefined) {
            require('deasync').sleep(0);
        }

        //returns an empty array or the real data
        return ret;    
},
```

Then i simply call it like this.

```
var data = syncGetMany(MongooseModel, queryObj);
// the rest of my code
```

**QUESTION: is there a way to get this done using ES6, or any similar library.**

PS: Not duplicate as other questions are not relevant to my context

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs - it allows to write and execute code as if it was sequential.

Comment: @amaksr some sample code using your library can be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplest way to get this code more cleaner is to use async/await, it's available in node.js version => 7.0. If I think well your model.find method returns promise.

```
async syncGetMany (model, query) {
    let ret;
    ret = await model.find(query);
    //ret is keeping body from response now, if error occured error is throwed as promise exception
    //Could do some sync ops on ret variable
    return ret;
}
```

When you are using async/await you should put your method execution into try/catch. But you can also catch errors inside syncGetMany method, probably it should looks like this:

```
async syncGetMany(model, query) {
    let ret;
    try {
        ret = await model.find(query);
        return ret;
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        return []; //empty array or any error string/object
    }
}
```

And your execution looks like you wrote with additional await operator (using es6 provide let/const operators for var operator replacement)
`let data = await syncGetMany(MongooseModel, queryObj);`

Article with async/await explanation:
https://blog.risingstack.com/async-await-node-js-7-nightly/

If you don't want to use Node v7.0 you should code something like this using promises and generators.

https://medium.com/@rdsubhas/es6-from-callbacks-to-promises-to-generators-87f1c0cd8f2e

I hope I helped.

**Update**
So when your mongoose instance doesn't supports promises there are three options (depends I think on node versions). In my opinion promises are cleaner way to make asynchronous request so I suggest using them.

First option (native promises):

```
syncGetMany(model, query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        model.find(query, (err, res) => {
            if(err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(res);
        });
    });
}
```

Second option (bluebird library, added Async postfix to all methods):

```
const mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
const Promise = require('bluebird');
Promise.promisifyAll( mongoose );

async syncGetMany(model, query) {
    let ret;
    try {
        ret = await model.findAsync(query);
        return ret;
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        return []; //empty array or any error string/object
    }
}
```

Third option (Node version => 8.0):

Using native promisify on function:
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

On our synchronous part (with async operator before function construction):
`let data = await syncGetMany(MongooseModel, queryObj);`

Comment: My mongoose instance is not using promises

Comment: I added promises support to your code with explanation, I have also made one mistake that synchronous part could be written without "await" operator, using "async/await" forces us to use "await" operator before asynchronous function execution.

Answer (score -1):

You can write and execute logic as if it was synchronous using [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs):

```
function synhronousCode(model, query) {
    function syncGetMany(model, query){
        return model.find(query).data; // data will contain result of resolved promise at this point
    };

    var data = syncGetMany(model, query);
    // do stuff with data
}

var nsynjs = require('nsynjs');
....
nsynjs.run(synhronousCode,{},model, query, function(){
    console.log('synhronousCode done');
});
```

nsynjs will evaluate code in `synhronousCode` in sequential manner: if some function returns promise (as `model.find` does), nsynjs will pause execution and wait until promise is resolved, assigns result to `data` property of returned value, and then continue execution.